# Express Middleware to populate a Jade variable for all app.get()'s

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a Jade file that all of my templates extend called layout.jade. In it I want to be able to have a logout button if the user is currently logged in (this is kept track of in req.session).

So layout.jade will have something like,

```
-if (loggedin)
  a.navButton(href="/logout") Log Out
```

The route for a page would look something like,

```
app.get("/foo", function(req, res) {
    res.render("foo", {loggedin: req.session.isValidUser});
});
```

The thing is, I don't want to have to populate the loggedin variable manually in every single route. Is there a way I can use Express middleware to automatically set some default options for the object sent to res.render? Or is there a better method to do this?

Basically I'm asking how I can have some set of variables always sent to templates, as well as the ability to have certain custom variables available in certain templates by manually setting them in the routes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems this is actually a documented feature I just had trouble finding, unless anyone has a better way of doing it; From the latest [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals),

> **app.locals**: Application local variables are provided to **all templates
>   rendered** within the application. This is useful for providing helper
>   functions to templates, as well as app-level data.

So in my login success function has,

```
req.session.username = profile.username;
app.locals.username = profile.username;
```

My logout function,

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    delete app.locals.username;
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

And finally in layout.jade/all of my templates,

```
- if(username)
  a.navButton(href="/logout") Logout
```

Comment: Wait, doesn't Node.js run in just one instance for all users? I mean, won't `app.locals` reference the same object for every user of the application?

Comment: `app.locals`  is definitely the wrong choice for data that is specific to a single request.  There are plenty of oppoortunities for data to get mixed between requests if trying to use `app.locals` for per-request data.  This appears to be a completely wrong answer that would have all sort of concurrency issues under load from multiple users.

Answer (score 5):

If you set `res.locals.loggedin` in the `/login` route, as hexacyanide suggests, this local will *not* be available in the route for `/foo`. `res.locals` is cleared upon every request.

you could instead try placing this above other routes:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  if(req.user){
    res.locals.loggedin = true;
    res.locals.currentuser = req.user;
  };
  next();
});
```

Pretty sure that if you modify req.user during your route, the `res.locals.currentuser` that you set before won't updated to be the new `req.user`. but not certain about that.

I actually use a custom `render` function for each page where I render a template, it looks like this:

```
function myRender(templateName){
  return function(req, res){
    res.locals.currentuser = req.user || null;
    res.render(templateName);
  };
};
```

and I use it like this:

```
app.get('/foo'
, function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.bar = req.query['bar'] || "";
  console.log('passing request to myRender middleware');
  next();
}
, myRender('foo-jade-template')
)
```

This has the advantage of only setting `res.locals.currentuser` when I am ready to render something, instead of before executing my route. So if I change `req.user` it is guranteed to have the most recent version at render time.

Comment: About your assumption that modifying `req.user` won't work - why wouldn't it? If a reference is stored, I don't see why... Unless you do `req.user = somethingElse;` later on.

Answer (score 1):

There is a line of code that is rather useful to you in the Express source:

```
// merge res.locals
options._locals = self.locals;
```

Therefore, when you run `res.render()`, Express will also take any locals that are stored in `res.locals` and pass them into the render. Therefore, all you have to do is set `res.locals.loggedin` to true, and then run `res.render()` as usual.

```
app.get('/login', function(res, res) {
  res.locals.loggedin = true;
});
app.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
  res.render('foo', {});
});
```

Comment: For me this answer is the best one.  res.locals is the correct way to set per-request vars, and you have access to it in middleware.